# Jenkins build periodically every 2 hours after 10 PM to next day 7AM

Tags: jenkins, build

H H(22-7)/2 * * 1-5 ----- not working

Please let me know correct example

Comment: Do you want to run this everyday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0 0,2,4,6,22 * * *`

This will trigger the job at 10 PM, 12 AM, 2 AM, 4 AM and 6 AM everyday.

In case you need to distribute load, you can replace the first `0` with an `H`.